Mediarecorder throws exception if Start-Stop quickly
I have a Mediarecorder hooked to a button where I record while the button is pressed and stops when the button is released. The code works fine:
            mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            mediaRecorder.Reset();
            mediaRecorder.SetAudioSource(AudioSource.Mic);
            mediaRecorder.SetOutputFormat(OutputFormat.AacAdts);
            mediaRecorder.SetAudioEncoder(AudioEncoder.Aac);
            mediaRecorder.SetAudioSamplingRate(16000);
            mediaRecorder.SetOutputFile(storagePath);

            mediaRecorder.Prepare();
            mediaRecorder.Start();

What I am finding, however, is that users don't know that the button needs to stay pressed so they are simply tapping the button, which is causing the mediaRecorder.Stop() to execute relatively quickly. This is throwing an exception:
Java.Lang.RuntimeException: stop failed.
   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment.InstanceMethods.CallVoidMethod(JniObjectReference instance, JniMethodInfo method, JniArgumentValue* args) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/obj/Release/net7.0/JniEnvironment.g.cs:line 20370
   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualVoidMethod(String encodedMember, IJavaPeerable self, JniArgumentValue* parameters) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods_Invoke.cs:line 66
   at Android.Media.MediaRecorder.Stop() in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/net8.0/android-34/mcw/Android.Media.MediaRecorder.cs:line 2477

I can also simulate this error by synchronously executing the prepare, start, and stop. However, I am confused why the exception throws because the prepare, start, and stop are to be excuted one after the other after each line executes - so theoretically, the prepare and the start have finished before the stop hits.
mediaRecorder.Prepare();
mediaRecorder.Start();
mediaRecorder.Stop();
The MediaPlayer has a OnPrepared event that I can hook to make sure the Prepare completed. The MediaRecorder on the other hand doesn't have such an event unfortunately.
How can I avoid this issue with Stop throwing an exception?

Because the time is so short, you can add a time limit to the thread.

To avoid this issue you can use minimum recording time threshold. I have same   problem in on of my application then I have used below code which help me to resolve my problem. Maybe it's useful for you.
Thank you
private long startTime;
private const long MINIMUM_RECORDING_DURATION = 1000; // 1 second

// When starting the recording
startTime = SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime();
mediaRecorder.Prepare();
mediaRecorder.Start();

// When stopping the recording
long elapsed = SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime() - startTime;
if (elapsed < MINIMUM_RECORDING_DURATION) {
    // Delay stop to ensure the minimum duration
    new Handler().PostDelayed(() => StopRecording(), MINIMUM_RECORDING_DURATION - elapsed);
} else {
    StopRecording();
}

// StopRecording method
private void StopRecording() {
    try {
        mediaRecorder.Stop();
    } catch (Java.Lang.RuntimeException ex) {
        // Handle the stop failed exception
    } finally {
        mediaRecorder.Release();
    }
}

